# Syntax error while executing a command from Ansible

Tags: sed, ansible, yaml

Please help resolving the below syntex error thrown from Ansible:

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.   mapping values are not
>   allowed in this context

The error appears to be in

> '/app/iap_workspace/portals/workpro/dev/sanity/ansible/system/log_check.yml':
>   Line 244, column 45

But may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The lines that appear wrong are these:

```
   - name: load average
     raw: uptime | sed 's/.*load average: //' | awk -F\, '{print $3}'| bc | nawk -v thres=2.0 '{if($1 < thres) print "GOOD"; else print "BAD";}'
                                        ^ here
```

I could be wrong but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes.

If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes.

For instance this arbitrary
example:

```
foo: "bad" "wolf"
```

Could be written as:

```
foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executable command is        uptime | sed 's/.*load average://' | awk -F\, '{print $3}'
No space after load average:
If you put space after ":" ansible will take as a part of its own syntax like how we are staring to use any attributes for ansible. 
For example- 
raw:(space) (your command).

Answer (score 0):

This command is not throwing "bad" with any threshold value. Moreover, we want load average equal to 15mins, meaning the 3rd value. Something I can see is that the last value position is not the fixed one. So can you give a command where we can get the 3rd value by differentiating the strings by `s/.*load average`?

Like this:

`uptime | sed 's/.*load average: //' | awk -F\, '{print $3}'`